# Find resonance, bandwidth, etc.. from Bode Plot

Tags: simulation, orcad, bode-plot

I am analyzing the following circuit simulation in pspice:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image]

I need to find the resonance and cutoff frequencies, bandwidth and the quality factor from the simulation. I know how to do it by hand but is there a way pspice can get it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to find the resonance and cutoff frequencies bandwidth and the
>   quality factor from the simulation.

Resonance is where it peaks at maximum (or when the phase goes through zero degrees).

Bandwidth is defined as the 3dB points on the bode plot (green curve on your plot) and Q is centre frequency divided by bandwidth. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit) is good on this. Snapshot: -

[image]

You should find Q to be about 3.18 if I've done my sums right.

Comment: but there's no way to find the exact point of resonance with pspice?

Comment: It's a simulator - it doesn't have any special knowledge of what your circuit is - it doesn't have human qualities of knowing what you are trying to simulate. Resonance is something we define and look for.

Comment: ok. I guess that makes sense